# Bluemix API Manager Swagger 2.0 import ignores "formData" variables

Tags: import, integration, swagger, ibm-cloud, swagger-2.0

In this code, path and query variables are imported, but the form data variable is not.
However, (non-IBM) Swagger UI displays it correctly.

```js
{
    ...
    "paths": {
        "/stuff/{p}": {
            "post": {
                "consumes": [
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "multipart/form-data"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "p",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "Path variable",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "q",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "Query variable",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "f",
                        "description": "Form variable",
                        "in": "formData",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: We are checking with the team that owns that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Management does not currently support form data parameters. Swagger is just the vehicle to get the meta-data into API Management. Since the feature is not there, form data parameters are explicitly ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there a roadmap for this and other functionality or an overview of Swagger-related features supported or not supported by the API Manager?

Comment: Hey Archimedix,

We're aware of the limitation, and are hoping to include this functionality in the 2nd or 3rd quarter of 2015, although that could be subject to change.